# Mono.fromFuture triggering doAfterTerminate early in chain. misunderstanding or bug?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm trying to set up automatic cleanup of temp files, but some strange things happen when a `Mono` created from a `CompletableFuture` (from the S3 sdk) comes into play. The temp file is deleted too early in the chain. I am wondering whether this is a misunderstanding of reactor from my side, or a bug.

I've condensed the code to mimic the behavior I'm experiencing.

I would expect the output of this test to be:

```
uploaded file response
do other stuff
clean up file
```

However it is:

```
clean up file
uploaded file response
do other stuff
```

When not creating a Mono using `Mono.fromFuture`, everything works as expected.

```
@Test
    void bla() throws InterruptedException {
        CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                // "uploading"
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "uploaded file response";
        });

        Mono<String> createTmpFile = Mono.just("create tempFile")
                .doAfterTerminate(() -> System.out.println("clean up file"));

        Mono<String> doPersistenceThings = Mono.fromFuture(future)
                .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                .then(Mono.just("do other stuff"));

        Mono.just("data")
                .flatMap(d -> createTmpFile)
                .flatMap(d -> doPersistenceThings)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);

        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
```

Comment: The reason is that you are using doAfterTerminate on an inner Mono instead of the outer Mono. Take a look at usingWhen operator: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#usingWhen-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: I've implemented the code using Mono.usingWhen and it works like a charm. Thanks @MartinTarjányi.